# I can't create a database diagram in VS2010 for SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010

For some reason, when I click `Add Diagram` in Server Explorer I am left with an empty tab for designing diagrams. However, there is no dialog box which usually asks what tables to add. The dropdown menu at the top called `Diagrams` also has all the buttons inactive.

What could be the reason?

I have my SQL Server Express running (checked in SQL Server Configuration Manager). Version - 10.1.

Comment: This is likely a permissions issue. Can you right click in the design diagram surface and select **Add Table**? Did you ever get the message *"This server does not have one or more of the database objects rqeuired to use database diagramming. Do you wish to create them?"*

Comment: When I right-click the design surface - nothing happens. I got the mentioned messaged - I clicked "Yes". Was it good choice?

Comment: Try creating a new database and building a new diagram there. It could be an issue with the given DB you are working on. You could also try creating a DB on another SQL Server instance.

Comment: I created another DB in Visual Studio - the effect was the same. What do you mean by another server instance? I installed the SQL Express server 2012 and it wasn't working. Reinstalled - still not working. Uninstalled and installed SQL Express 2008 - still the same.

Comment: Sounds like you need to repair or reinstall VS 2010 - it doesn't seem like it's an issue with the database server, but the SQL tooling in Visual Studio.

Comment: If you have access to SQL profiler I would run that and trace all SQL statements and error messages to see if that sheds any light.

Answer (score 2):

I switched to Visual Studio 2012 and I can build diagrams there. VS2010 on the same machine still has problems. VS2010 on my other computer - no problems. Still don't know what could be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

After running into this problem in Visual Studio 2010, I switched to using SQL Server Management, but got the same problem. After doing some searching, I found two articles that were able to fix this for me. The discussion here: 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d65c71f5-3887-4f2a-bbd3-e799a4ac6fdc/visual-studio-database-tools-error?forum=vstsdb

has information that installing a newer beta version installs the visual database tools for 2012, but when uninstalling does not set it back to the older version. There were two locations for files that had to be replaced. The directory and file name of the DLL (on an X64 machine) is: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\Visual Database Tools\dsref80.dll
There is a link to the dll in the posting.

There was also a second folder some people had to replace, which was also referenced at this link:
http://harshgupta71.blogspot.in/2013/02/the-specified-module-could-not-be-found.html
The directory and file name of the DLL (on an X64 machine) is: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSDesigners8
There was a download to the replacement files as well.

The other option instead of downloading these files is to rename the files/folders and then do a repair/reinstallation.

Answer (score 0):

I think that installing/re-installing the SQL Server Data Tools extension for VS 2010 should fix this problem.

You can download it here:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9b0228c6-15d1-44de-9279-66dde12bf861

Comment: I have the same problem but your link is broken.